# how to execute the next T-SQL when a before T-SQL throw an error?

Tags: t-sql, sqlite

I am working with SQlite and I have many T-SQL that I want to execute all of them in this way:

T-SQL1; T-SQL2, ... T-SQLN

My T-SQL are:

```
insert into myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,1);
insert into myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,2);
insert into myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,3);
...
```

With this T.SQLs I want to related records from the table1 with the table2. If any of the relations exist, there are no problem all the T-SQL is execute, but if for exameple there are a problem with the second, the first is execute but the third and the next T-SQL are not executed.

My quiestion it's if there are any way to continue execute the T-SQL and don't take care if some of the T-SQL throw an error, because what I want it's to have the relation, if some relation exists it's because other user created it, so at the end it's what I want, that the relation exists, so I would like to continue with the next T-SQL.

Is it possible?

However, if I try to delete a record that does not exists, the next T-SQL are executed, so SQLite does not take care about the error and continue with the following. Why when I try to add a new record it does not work in the same way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend checking if it is OK to perform the T-SQL rather than ignoring errors.

You can do this by:

```
DECLARE @count int

SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM myRelationTable WHERE IDTable1 =1 AND IDTabl2 = 1)
IF @count = 0 OR @count IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,1)
END


SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM myRelationTable WHERE IDTable1 =1 AND IDTabl2 = 2)
IF @count = 0 OR @count IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,2)
END


SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM myRelationTable WHERE IDTable1 =1 AND IDTabl2 = 3)
IF @count = 0 OR @count IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,3)
END
```

Which can very easily be wrapped within a stored procedure.

**As to your question** the answer is:
Sure, easily:

```
BEGIN TRY
    insert into myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,1);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  --Do nothing
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
    insert into myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,2);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  --Do nothing    
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
    insert into myRelationTable(IDTable1, IDTabl2) VALUES (1,3);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  --Do nothing    
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Really my problem is that I am using SQLite Expert to execute the T-SQL, but this program detect as error syntax the Begin try line.

Other way to solve the problem is to use the igonre keyword in this way:

```
insert or ignore into my table...
```

This makes that if exists an error, the ignore it and execute the next statement. But again, the "ignore" keyword is detected as an syntax error by SQLite Expert.

The "ignore" keyword belongs to the on conflict clouse. There are more information in this [link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).

Thanks.